# Conesequences of $\forall k\in \mathbb N \space NP\not\subseteq TISP(poly(n),n^k)$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, lower-bounds, space-time-tradeoff

Does $\forall k\in \mathbb N \space NP\not\subseteq TISP(poly(n),n^k)$  has any separation of classes or consequences?

> My main question is can use this to show that $P \neq NP$ or some thing useful about $P \neq NP$ .

Comment: Why do we need the $\forall$ quantifier here? If $NP$ is not a subset of $TISP(poly(n),n)$ then your statement should also be true for all $k>1$?

Comment: yes, they are equals. I thought they are different.

Comment: I think they are equals to $NP \not \subset TISP(poly(n),n^{o(1)})$ too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would imply that L⊊NP since L⊆TISP(poly(n),n^k) k∈N

Comment: It also can show $SC \neq NP$ in similar way.